# Customizing SharePoint Calender

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, web-services

Hi I am really new to sharepoint. I am running a team and would like to customize my calendar view with a function for my team members to submit a form for an event. So here are the steps:

1. Access Sharepoint
2. Create a new calendar event using a customized form fields
3. Event gets populated within the calendar and color code according to each team member
4. I will get a notification e-mail on the event creation with all the details populated in the field
5. The calender should have a drop down option to view each team members events

I believe this has been done before, but I am not sure where can I learn how to do this. If anyone could point me in the right direction please. I am not a coder and can only understand simple HTML. Please be gentle. =)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help you with number one, but calendar with colors is easy without any piece of code if you have any version of SP 2010:

- Add all your new custom fields as new [columns](http://www.techgrowingpains.com/2011/01/sharepoint-create-calendar-with-a-custom-column/)
- Create calendar views [based on team members](http://mscerts.programming4.us/sharepoint/sharepoint%202010%20%20%20specify%20how%20items%20in%20a%20view%20are%20filtered.aspx) (based on "Created by" field or something new like "Event owner", equal to your member name like "John Doe", use choice type for something new because names could be written in many ways. And one view per each person is needed)
- Insert views as [overlays](http://davidlozzi.com/2012/01/26/color-code-your-sharepoint-calendar/) to your calendar
- Set [alerts](http://www.hosting.com/support/sharepoint-2010/create-an-alert-for-a-folder-file-or-list-item) to new items (for view "All Events" and for "New items are added" option)

Each member will have his/her own color at left side navigation bar and each member view will be visible in drop down [breadcrumb navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BquIi.png) of the calendar.

Comment: Thanks for the advise on point 3 I will go try it out, Any advise on point 2,4 & 5?

Comment: So provide more information please, I think that no. 4 and 5 was answered, at least